# Form a circle in canvas by dragging the element on the ring

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

I would like to achieve the effect in the canvas for the circle. when user drags the element on the circle line the circle needs to form.

I am sharing the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eaho1z26/)  to show what I have done so far. in this I am able to create the circle but there is some issue with the calculation that I am not getting right
I have used the draggable element to drag the div on the line of the circle.

attaching Image for more understanding for the expected result
[image]

```js
$('.rotating_sqare').off('mousedown').on('mousedown', function() {

  self.rotateTick($(this).parent(), $(this));
})

this.rotateTick = function(_roteteDiv, rotateHandle) {
  var self = this;
  $(_roteteDiv).draggable({
    handle: rotateHandle,
    opacity: 0.001,
    helper: 'clone',
    drag: function(event) {
      var // get center of div to rotate
        pw = $(_roteteDiv)[0]
      pwBox = pw.getBoundingClientRect(),
        center_x = (pwBox.left + pwBox.right) / 2,
        center_y = (pwBox.top + pwBox.bottom) / 2,
        // get mouse position
        mouse_x = event.pageX,
        mouse_y = event.pageY,

        radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y),
        degree = Math.round((radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 100);
      degree += 85; // 75 is diff
      if (degree > 360) {
        return
      }
      // console.log(degree)
      self.setDegree(_roteteDiv, degree);

      // $(_roteteDiv).attr("hour",self.degreeToHour(degree))
      $(_roteteDiv).attr("step", (((degree - 90)) / 30).toFixed(1).split(".")[1])
    },
    stop: function(e) {}
  });
}
self.setDegree = function(_ele, _degree) {
  $(_ele).css("transform", 'rotate(' + _degree + 'deg)').attr("val", _degree);
  this.runCircleFunction(_degree)
}

this.runCircleFunction = function(_degree) {
  if (_degree < 0) {
    return
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas_left");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var lastend = 0;
  var data = (_degree / 360) * 100; //2.77; 

  var myTotal = 100;
  let canWidth = canvas.width - 5;
  let canHeight = canvas.height - 5;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canWidth, canHeight);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(canWidth / 2, canHeight / 2);
  ctx.arc(canWidth / 2, canHeight / 2, canHeight / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (data / myTotal)), false);
  // ctx.lineTo(canWidth / 2, canHeight / 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#f0be50";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#8e3900";
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
.rotating_sqare {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  background-size: cover;
  left: -5px;
  top: -127px;
}

.div_rotate {
  top: 120px;
  left: 116px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 80px;
  left: 25px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  BORDER-RADIUS: 100%;
}

canvas {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='one active'>
  <canvas id="myCanvas_left" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
  <div class='div_rotate'>
    <div class='rotating_sqare'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Updated the question with expected result image

Comment: please explain what is the problem in words like "the shape is not closed", and if so, add `ctx.closePath();` before `ctx.stroke();`.